# Rails Search return all itens instead of searched one's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, pg-search

I have a rails app that consists on a personal library and i had a search feature that started to always returning all items on database and not only the searched item.
The URL after each search comes like this, for example:

http://localhost:3000/users/user_id/books?search=Alquimia

But returns all and not only that specific one... Thanks in advance for all help you can give me.

The code is as follow:
(i'll post two ways i tryed, the first on using PGsearch)

1'ST TRY

> books_controller.rb

```
def index
    if params[:term].present? 
      @books = Book.search_by_full_name(params[:term])
      @books = policy_scope(Book)
    else
      @books = Book.all
      @books = policy_scope(Book)
    end 
  end
```

> _book_search_bar.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag user_books_path(:user_id), method: :get, class: "search-bar" do %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'term', params[:term], placeholder: "Enter book or author" %>
  <br>
  <br>
  <%= submit_tag "SEARCH BOOK", class: "btn-main" %>
<% end %>
```

> book.rb

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
 
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :loans
  

  has_one_attached :photo

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :author, presence: true

  include PgSearch::Model

  pg_search_scope :search_by_full_name, :against => [:title, :author],
    using: {
      tsearch: {
        prefix: true
      }
    }

end
```

2'ND TRY

> books_controller.rb

```
  def index  
    if params[:search]
      @books = Book.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%")
      @books = policy_scope(Book)
    else
      @books = Book.all
      @books = policy_scope(Book)
    end
  end
```

> _book_search_bar.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag user_books_path(:user_id), method: :get do %>
2    <%= label_tag  "Search for a book:" %>
3    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
4    <%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil %>
5  <% end %>
```

Comment: "params[:term].present?" - you're not passing that param.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev not passing it where? I have it on the form and on the controller

Comment: Ah, I quickly scanned your code and picked up controller from one version, but the form - from the other. Anyhow, you can break this into two much simpler questions: 1) does my form pass the parameters that the controller expects? 2) given records A, B, C, D and this query (using a hardcoded search term), why does running the query result in returning records A, B, C, D instead of just A, B?

Comment: "i had a search feature that started to always returning all items on database and not only the searched item" - so it worked and then it stopped working. That's something you can `git bisect` on and find the exact commit where the search got broken. Then you stare at the changes until you find what broke it.